# copy table subset sas

Tags: sas, copy, proc

I am new to sas and I still trying to figure out how it works. My problem is to copy only a subset of a table and I have tried the following:

```
proc copy in=inlib out=work;
   select mytable (obs=10000);
run;
```

However it looks like I cannot apply the obs option during the proc copy.
How can I achieve this with proc copy?

Comment: You can do this very easy with **data work; set mytable(obs=10000); run;**

Answer (score 3):

Use the SAS System option OBS=;  Don't forget to set is back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a proc copy here; a data step should do the job (perhaps with the exception of if the dataset is indexed?). Data steps are the main ingredient of SAS so it's a good idea to get used to them!

Just run:

```
data mytable;
set inlib.mytable (obs=10000);
run;
```

This way you can also use keep or where statements for more complex filtering or columns or observations.